# How can I add objects from the library (using Math.random for the position) using a button?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a little project where I'm asked to create a button which will randomly place an object from the library onto the stage. I understand how to place a predefined item from the library to the stage using a button and how to use a for loop to push new instances of an object into it, but I have no idea how to create, set random coords, and place a child onto the stage.

I'd post the code I have but none of it works even a little bit. I tried using getDefinitionByName and pushing that into an array, and then placing that onto the stage but nada. I can't seem to work this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know how to add the object to your stage there is not much more science to it.

```
//Your button
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addItem);

//function to generate random coord.
function addItem(e:MouseEvent):void {
   var c:DisplayObject = new YourItemInLibrary();
   c.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
   c.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
   addChild(c);
}
```

Comment: I have something very similar to this, but I needed to be able to the button place as many objects as the button is pressed. If you press the button 10 times, ideally there'd be 10 items spread randomly across the screen.

Comment: The button will do exactly that. Add an object every time it is pressed. The listener is never removed.

Comment: Sometimes I feel like I shouldn't be working with AS3... 

This worked perfectly! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with the library in AS3 (only AS2) so I can't help you there. The rest is fairly easy.

So you create an instance of your library item. Again, not sure how, so I will just create an example with a simple `Sprite`.

```
var inst:Sprite = new Sprite();
```

To add it to the stage, you call `addChild` on the main object. You should **never** call it on the `stage` itself unless you have a specific reason for doing so. In this case, I will assume that the main object will just be the primary `MovieClip` object, which can be referred to using the `this` keyword.

```
this.addChild( inst );
```

To randomly place it, we will use `Math.random()`. That method produces a number between 0 and 1. To place it randomly on the stage, we'll multiply that by the size of the stage.

```
// subtract the size of the object to prevent it from
// moving outside the bounds of the stage
inst.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth - inst.width;
inst.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight - inst.height;
```

So that will create an object, add it to the stage, and move it to a random location on the stage, without going outside the bounds of the stage. You just need to replace my generic `Sprite` instantiation with your library object and throw it all in a loop (which I can assum you know how to do, or at the very least can Google to figure out)